# I'm in the dialout group but I still have to sudo chmod every time I use the serial port

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've added myself to the dialout group but I'm unable to access it without sudo chmod every terminal session? How can l permanently solve this issue?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge modemmanager` and see if then `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` becomes permanent. Reboot is required.

Comment: Yesterday I installed Platform IO and used it's serial monitor and now it works. It hasn't for weeks.

$ ls -la /dev/tty* and this output came crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 for /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Tested it with a few MCUs and it works flawlessly now. I couldn't get to work before even though I was in the dialout group and so was the serial port.

Comment: Help? Did you use anything from my comment or it just worked?

Comment: It Just worked. Surprisingly I can't use the other USB port on my laptop to flash my MCU but the VS Code Plugin Platform IO did solve my original issue and I can now work conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of getting permanent access to your device, no matter the port you connect it to, is **creating a rule in the udev folder**. With it you associate some parameters of your device (typically the Vendor and Product ID) and establish the permissions for such device.

First of all, **get the information from your device:**

1. Plug it in your computer
2. On a terminal, type `dmesg` and take the information of your device from the last lines in the output

---

Once you have the information about your device, create a rule at the *udev* directory:

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
sudo touch 20-your-device.rules
sudo echo ATTR{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTR{idProduct}=="YYYY", MODE="0666" >> 20-your-device.rules
```

where *XXXX* and *YYYY* are the Vendor and Product ID that you obtained from the previous instructions.

Remember to log out and log in from your session for making it work. Otherwise you can manually reload the rules.